# drop down menu works in all browsers except internet explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-browser, mysqli

I have this code below where it is suppose to be able to display a list of modules in a drop down menu by using ajax to retrieve the modules from another page:

**code given below**

```
    $(document).ready( function(){

        jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url:  "module.php", 
        success: function(response){ 
        jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
        } 
        }); 
    });

...

<?php

    $moduleHTML = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

?>
```

module.php page:

```
<?php

     // connect to the database
     include('connect.php');

     /* check connection */
     if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
    }

    $moduleactive = 1;

    $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 


     $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

     $sqlstmt->bind_param("i", $moduleactive);

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 

     $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName);


    $moduleHTML  = "";  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
    } 


    echo $moduleHTML; 

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 


    ?>
```

What I don't understand is that the drop down menu manages to display a list of modules in all major browsers except for internet explorer which just still displays the "Please Select" option. Why does the drop down menu not able to display a list in internet explorer?

**UPDATE:**

I am going to scrap the ajax method and just paste the main php code into the original script

Comment: Did you look at the browser's message log?

Comment: @wallyk How do I access that?

Comment: @user1930247 Press F12 or Find it under Menu->Tools->Developer Tool in IE. One thing more u can alert the response as well to check what data is flooding in. Check jQuery is correctly adding on the page. Let me know if u able o fix it by the logs or not

Comment: @swapnesh Ok I opended up the window by pressing f12, which tab am I suppose to select to see the message? I went on the console tab but no errors are appearing there

Comment: @swapnesh I did an alert response and refresh the page, it displays a message from webpage alert showing the view source code of the module.php page

Comment: @user1930247 Change echo $moduleHTML; $sqlstmt->execute();  TO     $sqlstmt->execute();  echo $moduleHTML;  and let me know then

Comment: @swapnesh I did not see that I had an extra execute() underneath the echo. It has still not fix the problem but you have got rid of a extra execute() for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better off just using php in your own script to retrieve the modules using the same script using php/mysqli in same script

Comment: I think it's ok to answer your own question. Although I find some of the answers here more fitting to the actual question.
And even if you decide, that you found a better solution yourself, please don't pretend you talk to yourself. That is creepy...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    $(document).ready( function(){

        jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url:  "module.php", 
        success: function(response){ 
        jQuery('#container').html(response); 
        } 
        }); 
    });

...

<?php

    $moduleHTML = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<div id="container">';
    $moduleHTML .= '</div>'; 

?>
//In here some where make sure you are echoing <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?>
```

And in your module.php change here

```
 $moduleHTML  = '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">';  
 $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
    } 
    $moduleHTML.='</select>';
```

Comment: I can see in your code you have not included a "Please Select" option, would you put this option above the while loop?

Comment: @user1930247 Just edit like - $moduleHTML  = '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'; $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'; before while loop

Comment: @ubercooluk even though I applied your code and I already had an echo `<th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>`, it does not display a drop down menu at all.

Answer (score 0):

you should choose html function instead of append like this jQuery('#modulesDrop').html(response);

Comment: If I do what you stated `jQuery('#modulesDrop').html(response); ` then it just displays a blank drop down menu

Comment: first you just alert a message/response on success function under jquery ajax. if it displaying value then instead of jQuery text use $ on all occurences

Comment: Tried what you commented but still no list of modules appearing.